# Autodesk forge token exception

Tags: autodesk-forge

https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/  <- java i'm trying but
get

> buckets & objects exception333: java.lang.RuntimeException: Expected 200 but got 400, with body {"developerMessage":"The required parameter(s) client_id,client_secret not present in the request","userMessage":"","errorCode":"AUTH-008","more info":"http://developer.api.autodesk.com/documentation/v1/errors/AUTH-008"}

client id and secret  my account login -> my apps copy but can't get token

finally i want to use 3d viewr in my web(tomcat use java)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set up the client ID and secret for your Forge app in properly following [here}(https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/environment/setup/java?id=files-and-folders) - if you are unsure how to set up environment variables for your OS you can hardcode them here:

```
\\config.java
 public static class credentials{
        public static String client_id = "FORGE_CLIENT_ID";
        public static String client_secret = "FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET";
    };
```

You can step into your code in [oauth.java](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/oauth/2legged/java?id=oauthjava) here and check if the client ID and secret are present correctly:

```
\\oauth.java
String client_id = config.credentials.client_id;
String client_secret = config.credentials.client_secret;
OAuth2TwoLegged forgeOAuth = OAuthClient(scopes);
```

See the [full sample Java project](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/tree/java) here to get started quickly.

Comment: see the another answer i can't write comment

Answer (score 0):

downloading (https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/environment/setup/java?id=files-and-folders)  and Main class Running - > console is complete but open viewer.html error

```
google console log
1.Logger.js:175 No access token is provided, but authorization requested. This is a problem.
2.Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
3.viewer.html:83 onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:4



Main.java console
***** Sending createBucket request
***** Sending uploadFile request
Error creating bucket : {"reason":"Bucket already exists"}
***** Response for uploadFile: 
Uploaded object Details - Location: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/forge-java-sample-app-tud2dd7bnd8ltbaegqee5ua175mdulau/objects/my-elephant.obj, Size:12501
***** Sending Derivative API translate request
***** Response for Translating File to SVF: class Job {
    result: success
    urn: dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2UtamF2YS1zYW1wbGUtYXBwLXR1ZDJkZDdibmQ4bHRiYWVncWVlNXVhMTc1bWR1bGF1L215LWVsZXBoYW50Lm9iag
    acceptedJobs: class JobAcceptedJobs {
        output: {formats=[{type=svf, views=[3d]}]}
    }
}
***** Sending getManifest request
***** Haven't finished translating your file to SVF - status: pending, progress:0% complete
***** Haven't finished translating your file to SVF - status: inprogress, progress:0% complete
***** Finished translating your file to SVF - status: success, progress:complete
***** Opening SVF file in viewer with urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2UtamF2YS1zYW1wbGUtYXBwLXR1ZDJkZDdibmQ4bHRiYWVncWVlNXVhMTc1bWR1bGF1L215LWVsZXBoYW50Lm9iag
```

sorry I'm not good at english

I have verified that Main.class receives a token. However, no token is provided in viewer.html.

use localserver tomcat